# How to decide using MTAP over STAP in h264 rtp payload

Tags: h.264, rtp

I've been digging into encoding and streaming h264 over the past week. To night I'm implementing the rtp h264 payload.

According to [RFC 3984](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984) ("*RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video - February 2005*")
multiple new NALU were introduced. Among them MTAP (multi time aggregation packet) and the STAP (single time aggre...).

As the names indicating, in STAP mode, all units is assumed to have the same timestamps. Does not that mean we can't use STAP for VCL NAL units?

For example one may use STAP for transmitting NAL types 7 or 8 (SPS, PPS) but can't use STAP for types 1,2,3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use STAP packets for aggregating both VCL and Non-VCL NALUs that have the same presentation time, which should be the case if they are part of the same frame.

You're encoder should be providing a series of NALUs for the frame and they should have the same presentation time.

I've worked with encoders that produced a NALU byte stream containing all NALUs for the frame.  This byte stream was assigned a single presentation time.  I've also seen encoders that produced individual NALUs, which multiple would have the same presentation time if they were part of the same frame.

Comment: Thank you @Joel for the reply. So you think its the PTS. Actually I started to grab some NALUs from a h264 movie (25 FPS big buck bunny) and non of the nalus had the same PTS. Anyway maybe it was just that sample and so far your answer makes the best sense.

Comment: @pendrive glad I could help. I would say if the PTS is not the same between the NALUs then they can't be aggregated due to requirements of STAP. But if you want to reduce the number of packets in that case, then you can use MTAP. The streams I've worked with have Non-VCL NALUs that pertain to a VCL NALU, so they all have the same PTS and can be combined in a STAP packet